# Will MySQL optimize queries with trivial conditions like WHERE name=name?

Tags: mysql, sql

I'm using JDBC with a MySQL database. I want my web app (made using Java Servlet) to perform the following operations:

- Update a table entry with optional parameters
- Perform filtering of rows with optional parameters

Here is a draft of the code I made to achieve this:

### doUpdate(customer)

```java
public void doUpdate(Customer customer) {

    try (Connection con = ConPool.getConnection()) {
        PreparedStatement ps = con.prepareStatement(
                "UPDATE customer " +
                        "SET " +
                        "firstName = IFNULL(?, firstName), " +
                        "lastName = IFNULL(?, lastName), " +
                        "balance = IFNULL(?, balance), " +
                        "bookmarked = IFNULL(?, bookmarked) " +
                        "WHERE id = ?",
                Statement.RETURN_GENERATED_KEYS);
        ps.setString(1, customer.getFirstName());
        ps.setString(2, customer.getLastName());
        if(customer.getBalance() == null)
            ps.setNull(3, Types.DOUBLE);
        else
            ps.setDouble(3, customer.getBalance());
        if(customer.getBookmarked()==null)
            ps.setNull(4,Types.BOOLEAN);
        else
            ps.setBoolean(4, customer.getBookmarked());
        ps.setInt(5, customer.getId());
        if (ps.executeUpdate() != 1) {
            throw new RuntimeException("UPDATE error.");
        }
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

### doRetrieveByCond(minBalance, maxBalance, firstName, lastName, bookmarked)

```java
public List<Customer> doRetrieveByCond(Double minBalance, Double maxBalance, String firstName, String lastName, Boolean bookmarked) {
    try (Connection con = ConPool.getConnection()) {
        PreparedStatement ps =
                con.prepareStatement("SELECT id, firstName, lastName, balance, bookmarked FROM customer \n"+
                        "WHERE firstName LIKE IFNULL(?, firstName) \n" +
                        "AND lastName LIKE IFNULL(?, lastName) \n" +
                        "AND balance >= IFNULL(?, balance) \n" +
                        "AND balance <= IFNULL(?, balance) \n" +
                        "AND bookmarked = IFNULL(?, bookmarked)"
                );

        if(firstName == null)
            ps.setNull(1, Types.VARCHAR);
        else
            ps.setString(1, '%' + firstName + '%');
        if(lastName == null)
            ps.setNull(2, Types.VARCHAR);
        else
            ps.setString(2, '%' + lastName + '%');
        if(minBalance == null)
            ps.setNull(3,Types.DOUBLE);
        else
            ps.setDouble(3, minBalance);
        if(maxBalance == null)
            ps.setNull(4,Types.DOUBLE);
        else
            ps.setDouble(4, maxBalance);
        if(bookmarked == null)
            ps.setNull(5, Types.BOOLEAN);
        else
            ps.setBoolean(5, bookmarked);


        ResultSet rs = ps.executeQuery();
        List<Customer> list = new ArrayList<>();
        while(rs.next()){
            Customer customer = new Customer();
            customer.setId(rs.getInt(1));
            customer.setFirstName(rs.getString(2));
            customer.setLastName(rs.getString(3));
            customer.setBalance(rs.getDouble(4));
            customer.setBookmarked(rs.getBoolean(5));
            list.add(customer);
        }
        return list;
    } catch (SQLException e) {
        throw new RuntimeException(e);
    }
}
```

This way, I get a flexible way to access the database without having to repeat code for each combination of parameters. There are not many other ways to achieve this using Java Servlet I guess.  (**no, i won't use Hibernate or Spring.** It's for a web dev class in university)

What if you actually want to search for values that are actually NULL or update an entry column and set it to NULL? I could use a dummy object for this purpose.

Does the DBMS optimize these statements? Let's assume that every parameter is *null* in doUpdate. The statement would then be

```sql
UPDATE customer
  SET firstName = firstName, lastName = lastName, balance = balance, bookmarked = bookmarked 
  WHERE id = ?
```

Will the DBMS ignore *useless* operations like setting a field to itself?

Same question applies for the doUpdate.

Comment: The answer is that it _might_ optimize them.  I seem to recall that for Postgres this is the case, not sure about MySQL.  Run `EXPLAIN` on your expected query from the statement to investigate this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In MySQL, that no-op will not be free, but it will be cheap.  It gets to the row in the table, then realizes that the statement does not change anything.  So there is nothing to do with the row.

It *may* have locked the row (transactionally), so there *could* be some minor interference with other connections.

Bottom line:  It is not worth worrying about.